# Reading an XML File with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am new to xml and unable to find a way to get content in between tags.
My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<block1>
  <file name="c:\w0.xml">
    <word>Text</word>
    <number>67</number>
   </file>
  <file name="c:\w1.xml">
    <word>Text</word>
    <number>67</number>
  </file>
  <file name="c:\w2.xml">
    <word>Text</word>
    <number>67</number>
  </file>
</block1>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ to XML is a great place to start. Consider the following code to parse your XML.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> 
<block1> 
  <file name=""c:\w0.xml""> 
    <word>Text</word> 
    <number>67</number> 
   </file> 
  <file name=""c:\w1.xml""> 
    <word>Text</word> 
    <number>67</number> 
  </file> 
  <file name=""c:\w2.xml""> 
    <word>Text</word> 
    <number>67</number> 
  </file> 
</block1>";

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var block = from file in document.Descendants("file")
            select new
            {
                Name = file.Attribute ("name").Value,
                Word = file.Element("word").Value,
                Number = (int)file.Element("number")
            };

foreach (var file in block)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", file.Name, file.Word, file.Number );
}
```

You can, of course, load the XML directly from a file using XDocument.Load instead of using Parse to read an XML string. XDocument is in the System.Xml.Linq namespace. Frankly, I would start there, but there are other options to work with XML in the System.Xml namespace (XmlReader.Create, etc.).

Comment: @Anthony: not `XmlTextReader`. `XmlReader.Create`.

Comment: Thanks, John. Goes to show what I know. I've forgotten (almost) everything about other methods since LINQ came along! Very tragic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an XML Query language.  I would recommend [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) if you're using .Net 3.5 or XPath if you're using something earlier.  XPath has the advantage of being an industry standard, but LINQ to XML is a much 'cleaner' API, in my opinion.

[How to query XML with an XPath expression by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) - Tutorial on using XPath

[LINQ to XML Video Tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/204/Querying-XML-in-C-with-LINQ-to-XML.aspx)

[MSDN XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) - From the XPath Reference

[Location Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256039%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) - Includes *text()* function for example.