# Reading XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Day>
<Monday>true</Monday>
<Tuesday>false</Tuesday>
<Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
<Thursday>false</Thursday>
<Friday>true</Friday>
<Saturday>false</Saturday>
<Sunday>true</Sunday>
</Day>
<Time>
<dateTime>12:21</dateTime>
</Time>
```

I need to read the above xml file to fetch Day and Time, assing the data fetched to a variable. How to achieve this using c# ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565064/reading-an-xml-file-with-net?rq=1

Comment: Is it whole xml, or just part of it? What is expected result? Which day or days should be fetched? What have you tried?

Comment: you are asking question to let others accomplish your work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing a console program to load your XML from string.. You can load from file providing filepath as well.. (I have mentioned that statement too)..

This is your XML:

```
string xml = @"<testxml><Day>
<Monday>true</Monday>
<Tuesday>false</Tuesday>
<Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
<Thursday>false</Thursday>
<Friday>true</Friday>
<Saturday>false</Saturday>
<Sunday>true</Sunday>
</Day>
<Time>
<dateTime>12:21</dateTime>
</Time>
</testxml>";
```

Now declare an `XmlDocument()` and load xml into it..

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        //xDoc.Load(xmlpath);
```

Now your xml document is ready .. with `xDoc.Load(xmlpath);` can load from filepath.

Now provide xpath for nodes you want to access.. either using nodeList(SelectNodes) or just one node .. using selectSingleNode:

I am using selectNodes for days ..  and selectSingleNode for datetime.

```
            string xpath = "/testxml/Day/*";
            XmlNodeList xNode = xDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

            foreach (XmlNode node in xNode)
            {
                string day = node.LocalName;
                Console.WriteLine(day + ", value=\"" + node.InnerText + "\"");
            }
```

The above code prints node name (ie, day and its value true/false)

Now let's print datetime value:

```
            xpath = "/testxml/Time/dateTime";
            XmlNode node1 = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            Console.WriteLine(node1.LocalName + ", value=\"" + node1.InnerText + "\"");
```

That was simple example of playing with XML DOM :)

Now a whole code:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<testxml><Day>
<Monday>true</Monday>
<Tuesday>false</Tuesday>
<Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
<Thursday>false</Thursday>
<Friday>true</Friday>
<Saturday>false</Saturday>
<Sunday>true</Sunday>
</Day>
<Time>
<dateTime>12:21</dateTime>
</Time>
</testxml>";

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
            //xDoc.Load(xmlpath);

            string xpath = "/testxml/Day/*";
            XmlNodeList xNode = xDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

            foreach (XmlNode node in xNode)
            {
                string day = node.LocalName;
                Console.WriteLine(day + ", value=\"" + node.InnerText + "\"");
            }

            xpath = "/testxml/Time/dateTime";
            XmlNode node1 = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            Console.WriteLine(node1.LocalName + ", value=\"" + node1.InnerText + "\"");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Hope it helps .. let me know if you have any questions..

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Take a look at the class XDocument. There you can do something like

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(XMLPATH);
IEnumerable<XElement> day = document.Elements("Day");
```

Comment: I didn't try as I am new to c#. I am looking for ideas. Thank you for your answer